# CAPL typedef bool

Tags: capl

Does CAPL support something like typedef? My goal is to create a boolean:

```
    typedef char bool;
```

I am able to do this:

```
      enum bool {
        false = 0,
        true  = 1
      };
```

but it isn't what I was going for because I have to do:

```
      enum bool isValid()
```

instead of:

```
      bool isValid()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no typedef in CAPL. 
`enum` is the closest you can get regarding boolean values.

The following code shows the usage of such `enum`:

```
variables
{
  enum Bool {
    true = 1,
    false = 0
  };
}



on Start {
  enum Bool state; 


  // setting the value
  state = true;


  // accessing the integer value
  write("state (integer value): %d", state); // prints "1"


  // accessing the value identifier
  write("state (value identifier ): %s", state.name()); // prints "true"


  // usage in if-statement
  if (state == true) {
    write("if-statement: true");
  } else {
    write("if-statement: false");
  }


  // usage in switch-statement  
  switch (state) {
    case true:
      write("switch-statement: true");
      break;
    case false:
      write("switch-statement: false");
      break;
    default: 
      write("switch-statement: undefined");
      break;
  }
}
```